# Azure Pipelines integration test against Google Cloud SQL DB using cloud proxy

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, yaml, azure-pipelines, knex.js

I am managing a NodeJS cloud functions repo which performs some DB operations such as 'userExists' etc. and would like to integration test against my Google Cloud SQL DB. In order to do this on my local, I launch the proxy app on a specific port and then configure Knex to use this port.

However, I would also like to set up CI/CD for this using Azure Pipelines. Google allows downloading the proxy as a docker image, which I have done. I have made the service account key available to it, and launched it successfully, however, when I run my tests, they still cannot connect to the proxy.

The part of my pipeline's YAML file that deals with the proxy and running of tests looks like this:

```
- script: |
    docker run -d \
    -v 'qa-key.json':/config \
    -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 \
    gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.12 /cloud_sql_proxy \
    -instances=$(DBInstanceConnectionName)=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432 -credential_file=/config
  displayName: 'Run GCP Proxy'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Run Tests'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    customCommand: 'test'
```

A `test` command which runs the tests is available. The function that configures knex looks like this:

```
const connectKnex = () => {
    const config = {
        user: 'my_user',
        password: 'my_users_password',
        database: 'my_db',
        port: 5432
    }

    return knex({
        client: 'pg',
        connection: config
    });
}
```

I assume my problem occurs because the task that runs the proxy is no longer executing once the tests run, but I have no idea how to verify/fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1: I wasn't seeing the output from my docker container**

I copied the command to run the docker container directly from [google's support page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-docker). The problem is that this command contains the `-d` flag (detach), which causes the container to run in the background and hide its output, which makes for difficult debugging. Upon removing it, I was able to see the proxy image was unable to find the credentials file.

**Problem 2: Credential file not found**

I haven't been able to spend time finding a proper solution to this problem. Since I am running the proxy image on an Azure build server, I don't have access to an interactive terminal from which to try and access the image's file system to try and debug the mounting. The problem was fixed along with the next problem.

**Problem 3: I was uploading a placeholder file for the service account key, and populating it from a secret variable during the build process, instead of using the secure file feature on Azure Pipelines**

Uploading a secure file allows you to download the file during the build process, without having to worry about where it is stored when downloaded, as the location is stored in a variable. It is [dead simple to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-secure-file?view=vsts). I just included the location variable in the proxy launch command, and it ran smoothly.

**Problem  4: I need the proxy to still be running when I run the tests**

The proxy is a long-running process, so the pipeline task that launches it will keep running and blocking execution of the rest of the pipeline until the proxy stops. But the proxy needed to be running while running the tests run, so the only solution I could think of would be to put them in the same task.

I was able to do this by running the following command

```
<proxy launch command> & \
sleep 20 && \ //wait for the proxy to finish launching
yarn test && \
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) //kill the proxy once tests finish running
```

Finally, the yaml that downloads the file and runs the proxy and tests looked like this:

```
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: Download QA Key
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'qa-key.json'

- script: |
    docker run \
    -v $(Agent.TempDirectory):/config \
    -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 \
    gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.12 /cloud_sql_proxy \
    -instances=$(DBInstanceConnectionName)=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432 - 
    credential_file=/config/qa-key.json & \ 
    sleep 20 && \
    yarn test && \
    docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
  displayName: 'Run Tests'
```